# Laravel relationship with pivot table as for model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have theses tables :

chevals :

- id
- name

courses :

- id
- name

horses_races :

- id
- cheval_id
- course_id

For no french speakers, cheval = horse, and course = race.

I want to make a relation ship between horses and races.

Example : horses 1 has done 3 races, and race #4 has 15 horses

I create horses like this :

```
   $cheval = Cheval::firstOrCreate([
                           'name' => $name->textContent,
                          'sexe' => $sexe,
                          'age' => $age
                            ]);
       
                            $cheval->save();
```

I need to know how to do for the horses_race table at the saving moment and after that to something like :

race->get()
echo all_horses_for_these_race();

or

horse->get();
echo all_races_for_theses_horse();

I tried this

```
                        $cheval->courses()->save(['course_id' => $race->id, 'cheval_id' => $cheval->id]);
```

But I get :

Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::save(): Argument #1 ($model) must be of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, array given, called in /var/www/html/turfix/app/Http/Controllers/CourseController.php on line 234

My question is just : How to save the relation data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `attach()` method to **many-to-many relationship**.

```
$cheval->courses()->attach($race->id);
```

To get all horses for a race,

```
$race = Course::find($raceId);
$horses = Cheval::whereHas('courses', function ($query) use ($raceId) {
    $query->where('course_id', $raceId);
})->get();
```

To get all races for a horse,

```
$horse = Cheval::find($horseId);
$races = Course::whereHas('chevals', function ($query) use ($horseId) {
    $query->where('cheval_id', $horseId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel DOCS - Many To Many Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

```php
DB::transaction(function () {
    $cheval = Cheval::firstOrCreate([...]);
    $course = Course::findOrFail($courseId);
    $cheval->courses()->attach($course);
})
```

Comment: doing this always increments the horse_id

Comment: @clocharddasso maybe you always create new Cheval model?

Comment: With  $cheval = Cheval::firstOrCreate([
                           'name' => $name->textContent,
                          'sexe' => $sexe,
                          'age' => $age
                            ]); I guess it creates a new Cheval model, only if not exists ?

Comment: @clocharddasso sure, but you do not need to call `$model->save()` 
firstOrCreate vs firstOrNew

Comment: I deleted ->save() but still increments all horses id

Comment: Can you provide full code example?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/5gy9S6dz

Comment: @clocharddasso all works fine in my case. Can you try to use `dd($cheval);` and look at result?